# Does Entity Framework automatically load all of my data (not a reference and lazy load is off)?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework

I have a database first Entity Framework project. For every entity that I add, a collection is added to the DbContext for the entity. I explicity set `LazyLoadingEnabled = false` in the DbContext constructor. If I break into the following code and check the count of CustomerDepartments, I get the total count of the table. If I'm just adding a new record, I expect the count to be 0 before I add, and 1 after. I'm using this in a stateless environment, so loading the whole table just to add a record seems absurd. What am I doing wrong?

```
using (Model.SupportEntities support = new Model.SupportEntities(_state.Credentials, _handler.ReadWriteConnectionString)) 
{
    Model.CustomerDepartment department = Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Model.CustomerDepartment>(_insertObject);
    support.CustomerDepartments.Add(department);
    support.SaveChanges();
    _state.ReturnNewIdAsJson(department.CustomerDepartmentID);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I misinterpret your question, but shouldn't you be setting LazyLoadingEnabled to true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have misinterpreted how `DbContext` and `DbSet` works.

It maybe best if you get hold of a tool for logging EntityFramework SQL calls try `Clutch.Diagnostics.EntityFramework`.

When you call `IEnumerable<T>.Count()` on `DbSet<T>`, Entity Framework runs the following query

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableName;
```

But it does not load the whole table.

The ACTUAL call you want for the behavior you wanted was either

```
support.CustomerDepartments.Local.Count;
```

OR

```
support.ChangeTracker.Entries<T>().Count()
```

These will NOT hit the database.

You have to remember that `DbSet` is an abstraction for the Database table, so calling Count() on it should tell you how many rows there are in the table.

BTW. FYI. The convention is call name your `DbContext` to be `SupportContext`. `Model` named classes or namespace suggests they are your POCOs.